# Has something recently changed in Google Maps API v3 that is incompatible with mootools.js Java Script, causing controls to disappear?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, controls

We have a page that embeds Google Maps API v3 and recently (today?) the zoom controls and map background controls have gone missing.  No changes have been made to the code.  When we disable mootools.js, the controls come back.  Has something recently changed in Google Maps API v3 that is incompatible with the mootools javascript, which could cause controls to disappear?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by an older version of Mootools.

Can your try to use the latest version of mootools?

I use mootools 1.4.5 with build ab8ea8824dc3b24b6666867a2c4ed58ebb762cf0 and it does not work
If I use mootools 1.4.5 with build 74e34796f5f76640cdb98853004650aea1499d69, it works.

The error is in Function.implement and method bind.

First build:

```
bind: function(bind, args){
    var self = this;
    if (args != null) args = Array.from(args);
    return function(){
        return self.apply(bind, args || arguments);
    };
},
```

Second build:

```
/*<!ES5-bind>*/
bind: function(that){
    var self = this,
        args = arguments.length > 1 ? Array.slice(arguments, 1) : null,
        F = function(){};

    var bound = function(){
        var context = that, length = arguments.length;
        if (this instanceof bound){
            F.prototype = self.prototype;
            context = new F;
        }
        var result = (!args && !length)
            ? self.call(context)
            : self.apply(context, args && length ? args.concat(Array.slice(arguments)) : args || arguments);
        return context == that ? result : context;
    };
    return bound;
},
```

The second build has more protection for errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think Mootools breaks part of the global code of Gmaps, maybe the event handlers.

Load the Google Maps API Javascript after Mootools-core.js, that works for me.

I Tested that today with Gmaps API V3, and Mootools 1.4 and Mootools 1.5.

(Sorry, i do not speak english :D)

Answer (score 0):

this has happened to me couple of times before, all of sudden controls go funny and then it get fixed automatically after a day.
i got messed up with bootstrap rather then mootools in your case.

i found this helpful
add this in your style sheet:

```
#mapDiv img{ max-width: none; }
```